# Filling in Show[]

Tags: plotting, filling

Is it possible to fill the region between two `ListPlots`' in `Show[]`. Something like:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[f1,Joined->True]
plot2 = ListPlot[f2,Joined->True]
both = Show[plot1,plot2,Filling->{1->{2}}]
```

my lists f1 and f2 are huge and complicated and has to be computed and plotted separately, i.e. a solution of the form `ListPlot[f1,f2,{x,xmin,xmax},Filling->...]` is not what I'm looking for. 
Is this possible and how?

Minimal Example:

```
list1 = Table[-(x - 2)^2 + 1, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
list2 = Table[(x - 1)^2, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
plot1 = ListPlot[list1, Joined -> True,DataRange -> {0, 3}]
plot2 = ListPlot[list2, Joined -> True,DataRange -> {0, 3}]
both = Show[plot1,plot2]
```

Here I would like the region between the plots shaded.

As per the comments I should add that:

The lists `list1` and `list2` two themselves are lists/matrices. They have dimensions such as 6 times 110 each. Then the object `temp = {list1, list2}` has `Dimension[temp] =  {2,6,110}` which cannot be `ListPlot`ted straight away.

Comment: Just join `f1`and `f2`points in the same `ListPlot`, whatever your lists will be. Isn't contradictory to plot each list separately, to combine them afterwards with `Show` instead of plotting them together with `ListPlot`?

Comment: One could do that but rather not in this case.

Comment: Doesn't the following work?  `ListPlot[{list1, list2}, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, 3}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]`.

Comment: @JimB I added some more info to my question (final paragraph).

Comment: If the dimensions of `list1` and `list2` are `{110,6}` and the horizontal and vertical coordinates are in respective positions 3 and 5 in the list of 6 variables, then you could certainly use `ListPlot[{list1[[All, {3 5}]], list2[[All, {3, 5}]]}]`.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing this the hard way by joining rowX of list1 with rowX of list2 and then ListPlot this object and use `Filling`...unfortunately.

Comment: I'll link this to my other question they are very related. There it should be clear what the lists consist of. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164961/10325

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you must do this after the lists have been plotted, you can simply grab the lists from the plot,

```
lines = FirstCase[#, Line[x_] :> x, Nothing, Infinity] & /@ {plot1, 
    plot2};
ListLinePlot[lines, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well actually I have solved my problem since writing the question (by simply saving the lists separately and then ListPlot them together, hence no need for new code etc) but I'll leave the question alone since it has engaged some people. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could add your solution as an answer as well, in case anyone else stumbles upon this in the future :)

Comment: We're working on the solution :-) but the question differs from this in that there we shade the region before using `Show` : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164961/10325

Comment: @user6014 The solution is in this link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164969/10325

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to manually tackle the problem. Might be a little rough around the edges and need some clean up to be more robust, but its a start.

Generate polygon filling:

```
f1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
f2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
mins = If[#[[1, 2]] < #[[2, 1]], #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{f1, f2}];
maxes = If[#[[1, 2]] < #[[2, 1]], #[[2]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{f1, f2}];
joined = Join[mins, Reverse@maxes];
gr = Graphics[{LightBlue, Polygon[joined]}]
```

[image]

Combine with ListPlots:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[f1, Joined -> True];
plot2 = ListPlot[f2, Joined -> True];
both = Show[{plot1, plot2, gr}]
```

[image]

Comment: For this to work one needs to now the analytic form of the lists right (or at least a fit to them)?

Comment: I don't think so, I think the biggest requirement for this is that the two lists have points that line up exactly on the same x coordinates, like in your minimal example.

Comment: If they *are* parallel, you know that one list is always has a value lesser than the other list for every x value, so you can just do `f1 = Table[{x, 2 x + 1}, {x, 0, 10, .1}]; f2 = Table[{x, 2 x + 2}, {x, 0, 10, .1}]; joined = Join[f1, Reverse@f2]; gr = Graphics[{LightBlue, Polygon[joined]}]` without picking mins/maxes programmatically. If almost parallel means they still intersect than this isn't relevant.