# ListPlot two matrices on the same graph and shade the region between them

Tags: plotting

I have two lists of `Dimension[list1] = {6,110}` similarly for `list2`.

I would like to `ListPlot[{list1, list2}]` and then shade the region between the curve corresponding to the `nth` line of `list1` and the curve corresponding to the `nth` line of `list2`, (without really using `Show` unless its the absolute final step).

The object `temp ={list1,list2}` has `Dimension[temp] = {2,6,110}` which cannot be `ListPlot`ted straight away.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does this give what you need: `ListPlot[Join[list1, list2], Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> Thread[Range[6] -> List /@ Range[7, 12]]]`?

Comment: Holy cow this looks interesting, let me get back to you.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same color for the same curve? Your current code is beautiful but it gives two different colors for the curves that constitutes the boundary of the shaded region.

Comment: It would be nice if (1 and 7), (2 and 8),...(6 and 12) pairwise had the same color. Is this possible to implement?

Comment: Faq, I posted the comment as an answer with the styling feature added.

Comment: Yes I'll check it out, and will probably accept the answer in a minute. Thanks for help really nice! @kglr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1 = Mean[3 # + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], {6, 110}]] & /@ Range[6];
list2 = list1 + 3 (StandardDeviation /@ list1);
temp = {list1, list2};
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[ ;; 6]];
filling = Thread[Range[6] -> List /@ Range[7, 12]];

ListLinePlot[Join @@ temp,  PlotStyle -> colors, Filling -> filling, 
 PlotLegends ->  SwatchLegend[colors, StringJoin["pair", #] & /@ (ToString /@ Range[6]), 
   LegendLayout -> {"ReversedColumn", 1}], ImageSize -> 500 ]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> ***is there a way to say let curve 1 in the numeration of filling be dashed while curve 7 solid. Meanwhile curve 2 solid while curve 8 dashed and so on?***

Instead of `PlotStyle -> colors` above use  `PlotStyle -> styles` where

```
 styles = Join[Directive[#, Dashed]& /@ #, #]& @colors
```

to get

[image]

Comment:  Let me try this out a minute.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution!

Comment: @Faq, glad it was useful. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: One final follow up, is there a way to say let curve 1 in the numeration of `filling` be dashed while curve 7 solid. Meanwhile curve 2 solid while curve 8 dashed and so on?

Comment: Faq, please see the update.

Comment: Great, awesome done! :-)