# shaded area in plot

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting the graph below  using the following code. The problem is that I need to make the area between the green and red curve shaded, but I can't make this work using Filling. I'd appreciate any ideas. (Have already tried the solution in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164836/filling-in-show), which fails strangely because it only plots the left half of the red line)

[image]

```
    x = d;
    y = d^2;
    z = Max[0, 2 (d - 1/2)];
    p1 = Plot[x, {d, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{
RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 
        0.709798]}, {"Assignment by lottery"}], {0.282, 0.8}], 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]];

    p2 = Plot[y, {d, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{
RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 
        0.194885]}, {"Complete equality"}], {0.25, 0.9}], 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885]];

    p3 = Plot[z, {d, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{
RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179]}, {"FCFS"}], {0.145, 0.7}], 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179]];

    Show[{p2, p1, p3}, AxesLabel -> {F[t], Subscript[L, P][F[t]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[{FontColor -> Black}, {FontSize -> 16}]]
```

Comment: Please, post the code not an image.

Comment: `Filling->{2->{3}}`

Comment: Have you tried doing it all under a single `Plot`? (I'd try it myself, but without the code here as text, I can't try it out and modify it without manually retyping everything...that's why it's always useful to post code, not images of code! :) )

Comment: @yarchik Thank you, I now copy the code

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks. when I add your suggestion to Show[], it gives the following error: OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option Filling for Graphics.

Comment: @thorimur Thank you. I now have copied the code instead of the image. The reason I didn't use a single plot is that I set different specifications for p1,p2,p3 plots, and I don't know how to do that in a single plot comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{x, y, z}, {d, 0, 1}, Filling -> {3 -> {2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend @ {"Assignment by lottery", "Complete equality", 
    "FCFS"}, {0.35, 0.7}],
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
   RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], 
   RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {F[t], Subscript[L, P][F[t]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[{FontColor -> Black}, {FontSize -> 16}], 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Use `Filling -> {2 -> {3}}` to get

[image]

Comment: @kgir Thanks a lot! This is great. There's only one small issue: the legend font appears to be larger in the output of your code. Is there a way to reduce the font of the legend? (but not the font of the axes)

Comment: @afshi7n, you can use `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{"Assignment by lottery", "Complete equality", 
    "FCFS"}, LabelStyle -> 12], {0.35, 0.7}]` (or use your desired fontsize in place of `12`)

Comment: Thank you so much